# Placing Multiple Criterion in One IF Statement Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How can I fit multiple AND/OR criterion in one If statement in Excel VBA
without stretching across one line?
Whenever I enter the extra the criterion to a new line, a compile 
error comes up.

[image]

Comment: Put a `_` after a space at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your If statement needs to be in one line or if you want it to be over two lines use an underscore.

```
If i.Value = "Device Name" _
Or Left(i.Value, 11) = "Average for" Then
    i.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```